# Merge contents of two partitions into one singular partition

Tags: debian, partition, raid

I have a machine that has a 20GB FS at `/dev/md1` mounted on `/`, and a ~200GB FS at `/dev/md2` mounted on `/home`.  A large amount of data will soon be stored in `/var`.  How can I  merge these two partitions into one larger partition without wiping the system?  If this is not easily possible, what is the easiest way to make the larger partition be mounted at `/var` and the smaller be mounted at `/`, without corrupting everything like user data and anything that's already in `/var` up?

The machines are running Debian 7.10.  While it makes little difference, I'm actually having this issue on two more or less identical machines.  I don't have physical access to either of them.  They can be restarted as often as necessary as they are not yet "live" or in production.

Comment: How much data do you currently have on the partitions? Can you take the machine down for maintenance (and e.g., boot from a live cd?) And this data that's going in `/var`, could you use a symlink (or bind mount) to put it in `/home` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately the fix I found was similar to the one @Anthon posted.

I ended up making a directory (`VAR`) in `/home`.  I copied the contents of `/var` into that, then changed `/etc/fstab` such that `/dev/md2` was being mounted at `/var`.  Then I rebooted the system.  When it came back I created a new `/home` directory (now ending up on `/dev/md1`), moved each of the user accounts (sitting in `/var`) into `/home`, and then moved the contents of (what is now) `/var/VAR` into `/var`.  Then I restarted the machine to fix issues involving `/var/lock` and `/var/run` being messed up.

While this is very messy, it's the cleanest way I found to resolve the issue, as it avoided having to deal with symlinks and other messes in `/home`.

Answer (score 3):

As your `md2` is not empty, the easiest way is to `rsync` the data from `/var` to the new partition and then make a soft link:

```
 rsync -xav /var /home/VAR
 mv /var /var.org
 ln -s /home/VAR /var
```

This would be best done when booted from a live distro (with mounted `md1` and `md2` and  adapted paths), if that is not possible, you might want to `rsync` another time in order to catch changes during the rsync (booting from a live system is better).
If you do this from a live distro, you can reduce the downtime (as @cas indicates) by doing an initial `rsync` on the working system, so that just the changed files need syncing after reboot in the live system.

As an alternative to making the soft link you can consider using `bind` mounting `/home/VAR`/  on `/var`. I am not sure it this has advantages or not.

Once everything you check everything is there and working, you can remove `/var/org`

Comment: You could do `mount -o remount,ro && rsync ... && mv ... && ln -s ... && mount -o remount,rw` . No idea if that would work on a busy fs.

Comment: @Dani_l since `md1` is mounted on `/` I don't think you can remount `ro`

Comment: +1. To minimise downtime, I do the initial `rsync` while the system is working normally.  When I'm ready, I reboot to a rescue CD/USB, mount partitions RW as required, and run a final rsync (which will take only seconds or minutes rather than hours).  Then rename & symlink as in Anthon's answer, then reboot.   You can run `rsync` as often as you like, for days or weeks before you do the reboot and final rsync.  This allows you to easily schedule the transition downtime for a time that suits you & your users/employer/etc.  Write a shell script to run the `rsync` with all the required options.

Comment: @cas Minimizing downtime is indeed often necessary. Is it ok if I merge your recommendation in the answer (attributed)?

Comment: sure.  comments are always available for 'stealing' into answers.  this has come up in meta on various SE sites several times, and i agree with the overall consensus.  if i'm too lazy to write a real answer and someone else 'steals' from my comment, they deserve the rep for not being lazy.  or, as in this case, you'd already written roughly the same answer I would have written so there was no point in me writing a dupe answer...just a comment to add some extra useful info.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution, as [derobert suggested in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277709/merge-contents-of-two-partitions-into-one-singular-partition#comment482689_277709), is to leave (most of) the existing files where they are, only move the one directory that's going to receive big files, and create a symbolic link to make the expected path point to where the files will actually be stored. For example, if you're converting this server to hold a lot of mail, you might do

```
service postfix stop         # or whatever you need to do to stop writing to /var/mail
mv /var/mail /home
ln -s ../home/mail /var/mail
service postfix start
```

If the files are going into a new directory, you have nothing to move, just create the directory in the big partition and create a symbolic link to it in `/var`.

If the files really have to be under `/var`, you can move move `/home` to the small partition and move `/var` to the big partition. But to do it safely, you need to make sure that nothing is using the files you're moving, which is problematic if you don't have physical access.